# Существуют ли плагины для облегчения насадки вёрстки на wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Хочу насадить вёрстку на ВордПресс,ни разу этого не делал, подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь инструменты(плагины) которые облегчат мою задачу.
Ps. Верстка 3х страничного сайта.

Comment: а зачем Вам "движок" для 3х страниц ? о.о `Инструментов, вроде, нету`

Comment: Это вопрос аля "какой бензин поможет изменить цвет автомобиля"